# Using scikit-learn on Databricks

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, databricks, azure-databricks

Scikit-Learn algorithms are single node implementations. Does this mean, that they are not an appropriate choice for building machine learning models on Databricks cluster for the reason that they cannot take advantage of the cluster computing resources ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not appropriate, in the sense that, as you say, they cannot take advantage of the cluster computing resources, which Databricks is arguably all about. The raison d'être of Databricks is Apache Spark, and specifically for ML tasks, its ML library [Spark MLlib](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html).

This does not mean that you cannot use scikit-learn in Databricks (you'll find that a Databricks cluster comes by scikit-learn installed by default), only that it is usable for problems that do not actually require a cluster. If you want to exploit the cluster resource capabilities for ML, you need to revert to Spark MLlib.

Comment: Does this mean using scikit lean on Databricks is equivalent to running it on my laptop in Jupyter notebook ?

Comment: @learner "equivalent" is a strong word and rather vague here; provided that the computing capacity of the Databricks *driver* machine and your laptop are comparable, yes.

Comment: databricks is often used to train multiple single-node models in parallel, like, doing hyperparameter tuning.  Also, there is also support for single-node clusters

Answer (score 1):

I think desertnaut hit the nail on the head here.  I believe Scikit Learn algos are designed only for non-parallel processing jobs, and all the MLlib stuff is designed to leverage cluster compute resources and parallel processing resources.  Take a look at the link below for sample code for standard regression and classification tasks.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html

In addition, here are some code samples for different clustering tasks.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html

That should probably cover most of the things you will be doing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it depends on the task at hand. I see two general scenarios:

1. Your data is big and does not fit into memory. Go with the Spark MLlib and their distributed algos.
2. Your data is not that big and you want to utilize sheer computing power. The typical use case is hyperparameter search.

Databricks allow for distributing such workloads from the driver node to the executors with `hyperopt` and its `SparkTrials` (random + Bayesian search).

Some docs here>
http://hyperopt.github.io/hyperopt/scaleout/spark/

However, there are much more attempts to make the sklearn on spark work. You can supposedly distribute the workloads through [UDF](https://towardsdatascience.com/3-methods-for-parallelization-in-spark-6a1a4333b473), using [joblib](https://github.com/joblib/joblib-spark), or [others](https://github.com/Ibotta/sk-dist). I am investigating the issue myself, and will update the answer later.